# Number theory $a|d$

Tags: number-theory

Suppose in $\mathbb{N}^** \mathbb{N}^*$ the equation $(E): x^2+y^2+xy-13x=0$.

We set $x=ad$ and $y=bd$ and $d=GCD(x,y)$.

How can I prove that $a|d$?

Comment: Could you clarify what your notation is? What is $\mathbb{N}*$? What do you mean with $PGCD$?

Comment: Prove that $a/d$ what?

Comment: Perhaps you mean $a\mid d$?

Comment: yes I made some correction

Comment: @Dedalus I mean $\mathbb{N}^{*2}$

Answer (score 3):

Presumably $\mathbb N^*$ is the non-zero naturals.  Plug in your values for $x,y$ and divide by $d$, getting $$a^2d^2+b^2d^2+abd^2-13ad=0 \\a^2d+b^2d+abd-13a=0$$ and note that all the terms have a factor $d$ except the $13a$.  Therefore $d$ must divide $13a$.  We can exclude $d=13$k being a multiple of $13$.  We can do that by saying that if $d=13k$ we can divide out the $13$ to get $$a^2k+b^2k+abk-a=0$$ but clearly $a^2k+b^2k \gt a$ so this cannot be the case.  This proves $d|a$, so write $a=md$ and we get $$m^2d^3+b^2d+mbd^2-13md=0\\m^2d^2+b^2+mbd-13m=0$$ and $m$ divides $b^2$, contradicting the assertion that $\gcd(a,b)=d$.  I still don't have $a|d$, but do have that there is no solution.

Comment: Could you please explain more?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused here, but doesn't $13a=d(\ldots)$ mean that $d$ divides $13a$, rather than the other way around?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen:  you are right, I got backwards.  And that led me on...

Answer (score 0):

If $\rm\ a\mid x\ $ then $\rm\:a\mid (x,y)\iff a\mid x,y\iff a\mid y.\ $ In particular, for $\rm\ a \,=\, x/(x,y)\ $ we have

$$\rm\: x/(x,y)\mid y\iff x\mid  (xy,y^2)\iff x\mid y^2,\ \ true\ by\ \ \ y^2 = -x^2-xy+13x\quad{\bf QED}$$